# How to disable the auto hide feature(on mouse leave) of toolbar menu in an iframe containing pdf document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, razor

I have tried accessing the contents of Iframe window and then changing its script but as obvious its not possible to access the contents of Iframe window, so is there any way round to disable the auto-hiding of the toolbar menu

This is the HTML Iframe being accessed:

```
<iframe id="hiddenFrame" src=""></iframe>
```

Source for this iframe is set dynamically from C#:

```
<iframe id="hiddenFrame" src="/xxxxxxxxxxx/Shared/OrderView/GetSpreadsheet/33?formName=P1.pdf#scrollbar=0"></iframe>
```

Script to change the default behavior of toolbar menu

```
var frame = document.getElementById('hiddenFrame');
var subWindow = frame.contentWindow;
var subDocument = subWindow.document;
$(subDocument).find("body viewer-pdf-toolbar#toolbar").css('transform', 'none !important');
```

On Inspecting the Iframe window the source script is as follows:

```
<body>
<viewer-pdf-toolbar id="toolbar" style="transform-origin: 50% 0px 0px; transform: translateY(-100%);"></viewer-pdf-toolbar>
<div id="sizer" style="width: 663px; height: 912px;"></div>
<viewer-password-screen id="password-screen"></viewer-password-screen>
<viewer-zoom-toolbar id="zoom-toolbar" style="right: -8.5px; bottom: 0px;"></viewer-zoom-toolbar>
<viewer-page-indicator id="page-indicator" style="top: 0px; opacity: 0;"></viewer-page-indicator>
<viewer-error-screen id="error-screen"></viewer-error-screen>

<script src="pdf_fitting_type.js"></script><iron-a11y-announcer></iron-a11y-announcer>
<script src="toolbar_manager.js"></script>
<script src="viewport.js"></script>
<script src="open_pdf_params_parser.js"></script>
<script src="navigator.js"></script>
<script src="viewport_scroller.js"></script>
<script src="zoom_manager.js"></script>
<script src="gesture_detector.js"></script>
<script src="pdf_scripting_api.js"></script>
<script src="chrome://resources/js/util.js"></script>
<script src="browser_api.js"></script>
<script src="coords_transformer.js"></script>
<script src="metrics.js"></script>
<script src="pdf.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>

<embed id="plugin" type="application/x-google-chrome-pdf" src="http://000.000.00.00/xxxxxxxx/Shared/OrderView/GetSpreadsheet/33?formName=P1.pdf#scrollbar=0" stream-url="blob:chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/adb53268-d7c1-4eb2-9efd-8c9f154f88dc" headers="Content-Type: application/pdf
Cache-Control: private
Content-Disposition: inline; attachment; filename=Preview.pdf
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Date: Mon, 02 Jul 2018 09:45:46 GMT
" background-color="0xFF525659" top-toolbar-height="56" top-level-url="undefined"></body>
```

Comment: Can you post code that would allow one to see what you have tried that is not working?

Comment: i have added the code, please check it

Comment: Can you post more about what kind of iFrame you are trying to access?

Comment: it's a simple html iframe, having a pdf document as its content

Comment: Would it be possible for you to add the code using the "embed code" option on Stack Overflow so that I can run it and see exactly how it is displaying?

Comment: @JakeChasan if you wish to see how it gets displayed, you just have to use an IFRAME and pass its "src" value as that of the PDF location(That's it what I do, though in my case the "src" value comes from server side). The embed code posted above is the code generated by IFRAME when its content is a PDF